# Making a clickable object with Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, raphael

I have created a 3d looking circle and want it to be clickable and display its data.  I can't seem to get it to work though.  Can someone please help me figure this out???  The code where I try to do this is near the bottom....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Raphaël · Ball</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo-print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
    <script src="raphael.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        Raphael.fn.ball = function (x, y, r, hue) {
            hue = hue || 0;
            return this.set(
                //this part is the drop shadow
                this.ellipse(x, y + r - r / 5, r, r / 2).attr({fill: "rhsb(" + hue + ", 1, .25)-hsb(" + hue + ", 1, .25)", stroke: "none", opacity: 0}),
                //this part is the top part of the circle
                this.ellipse(x, y, r, r).attr({fill: "r(.5,.9)hsb(" + hue + ", 1, .75)-hsb(" + hue + ", .5, .25)", stroke: "none"}),
                //this is the inner glow part from the top
                this.ellipse(x, y, r - r / 5, r - r / 20).attr({stroke: "none", fill: "r(.5,.1)#ccc-#ccc", opacity: 0})
            );
        };
        window.onload = function () {
            var R = Raphael("holder"), x = 300, y = 100, r = 100;
            //I cant tell what numbers are passed into here?????
            R.ball(x, y, r, Math.random()).data("i", i).click(function () {
            alert(this.data("i"));
         });
        };
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="holder"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if i get wrong here ... but a sample of this code is working fine for me .... unfortunately i cant seem to find the `var i` in your code which you are passing to `data('i',i)` .... declare `var i = something;` or try this data('i','Hello') to let you know that it works ... hope it helps .

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npzMU/)**

Comment: you should try what i suggested ..... you just have to declare a var i in your code .... thats it ....